# Javascript: iterate through array and add % after each element except last

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to add a % after each element in the array except the last. So far I have come up with this:

```
var array = [a, b, c];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      var outcome += array[i] + '%';
}
```

Outcome:

```
a%b%c%
```

How can I fix this so the % does not appear at the end of the outcome?

Comment: `var outcome = array.join('%');`

Comment: you can also remove last item of a string by using  `slice`

Comment: ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((a,c,i,ar)=> [...a, c, ...ar.length - 1 === i ? []:['%']],[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Array.prototype.join method in order to get what you're after:

```js
console.info(['a', 'b', 'c'].join('%'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil, updated.

Answer (score -2):

Check if the current element (value of i) is not the last element. If it's the last element don't concatenate a %, for all others concatenate with the %.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr.length -1) {
       var outcome += arr[i] + '%';
    }
}
```

Comment: this will full skip the last element, instead of just not adding the `%`